# CLR/C++ reading a textfile and writing to multiple textboxes

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I've read quite a bit online on how read and write but is another story with multiple textboxes.

```
private: System::Void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         SaveFileDialog ^ Save_file = gcnew SaveFileDialog();
         Save_file->Title = "Save your Character sheet";
         Save_file->Filter ="Text file|*.txt";
         Save_file->ShowDialog();

         if (Save_file->FileName != "")
         {
             System::IO::StreamWriter^ sv = gcnew System::IO::StreamWriter(Save_file->OpenFile());
             sv->WriteLine(Character_Nameinput + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Char_Descinput + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Stand_nameinput + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Stand_descinput + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Goals_input + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Impulses_input + "\n");
             sv->WriteLine(Notes_input + "\n");
             sv->Close();
             MessageBox::Show("Your character has been saved.");
         }
 }
```

This is a chunk of my saving event. There are more textboxes but it is unneeded information because it is essentially the same for every box.

```
**private: System::Void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         OpenFileDialog ^ Load_file = gcnew OpenFileDialog();
         Load_file->Title = "Load a Character sheet";
         Load_file->Filter = "Text file|*.txt";
         Load_file->ShowDialog();
         if (Load_file->FileName != "")
         {
             System::IO::StreamReader^ ld = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(Load_file->OpenFile());
             Character_Nameinput->Text = ld->ReadToEnd();

             ld->Close();
         }
}
```

This is what I have so far. It loads the entire file into the first text box I'm wondering if their is a better way or how could I separate the text file?